# Is it possible to bundle a Shiny app (and packages) for deployment to own Shiny Server?

Tags: r, deployment, shiny

When deploying Shiny apps to a self-hosted version of Shiny Server is it possible to "bundle" the app and packages in some way?

My Shiny app depends on a whole bunch of packages that are install in my dev (RStudio) environment. Do I have to manually install those packages on the Shiny Server machine before deploying my app?

If I *do* have to install the packages on the Shiny Server machine, how would I stop package updates breaking existing applications? Or are we back to the old "Windows DLL hell" type of problem where you can't isolate the shared libraries?

I know how to deploy apps to `/srv/shiny-server/`. It's the package dependency stuff that I'm not too sure about.

Comment: If you mean multiple apps with different package dependency for each app, you can use `packrat` with Shiny Server. See https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/216528108-Deploying-packrat-projects-to-Shiny-Server-Pro While the link says Shiny Server Pro, I believe it should work for the open source version as well.

Comment: That looks interesting, and may well address the versioning issue.I'm also interested in whether deploying a single app requires me to install packages manually on the Shiny Server machine, or whether I can "publish" or "bundle" from RStudio and then just copy that bundle to Shiny Server and it just all works.

Comment: Seems like a pain to have to list all the packages I used in building my app and then go over the server to install them again when the R project should know what it needs. Maybe packrat addresses that problem too?

Comment: You have to install all dependencies in your server. What you described is the way shiny is implemented at  https://www.shinyapps.io/  .

Comment: Another convenient workflow is to install rstudio server in the server. So you develop and deploy on the same environment.

Comment: Yes `packrat` manages your package dependencies (this works best if you start your project with RStudio with packrat enabled). Also the `unbundle` process would install the R dependencies in a subfolder of the shiny app folder (it still takes time especially if some packages need compilation, but the entire process is automated).